# How to use TcpClient in a way that accounts for erratic stream response

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

My C# skills are still rather basic, but through trial-and-error I mananged to create a Windows Forms server that allows multiple connections and a client that sends messages and gets responses.
However, I know from distant VB experience that requests may not always match answers 1:1 as the connection can be erratic.
My current code "works", but probably it's not good. The client cannot deal with a fragmented answer from the server, and if it receives no answer, it will hang.

Could my code be proofed to take this into account? Sorry if I'm using things all backwards, appreciate it if someone can bear with me!

Server code:

```
        public List<TcpClient> tcpClient = new List<TcpClient>();

        public async void ListenForConnection(int index)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5036);
            listener.Start();
            while(true)
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Add(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
                    WaitForMessage(tcpClient.Count - 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
        }
        
        public async void WaitForMessage(int index)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient[index].GetStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tcpClient[index].GetStream());
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    int recv = 0;
                    foreach (byte b in buffer)
                    {
                        if (b != 0)
                        {
                            recv++;
                        }
                    }
                    string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv); 
                    string response = "You said: " + request;
                    sw.WriteLine(response);
                    sw.Flush();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (!tcpClient[index].Connected)
                    { return; }
                }
            }

        }
```

Client code:

```
        public TcpClient tcpclient;

        public async void ConnectToServer()
        {
           bool connected = false;
           while(!connected)
                try
                {
                    tcpclient = new TcpClient();
                    await tcpclient.ConnectAsync(IPADDRESS, 5036);
                    connected = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
        }

        public string ServerData(string request)
        {
            if (!tcpclient.Connected)
                return "";
            int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(request + 1);
            byte[] sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

            NetworkStream networkstream = tcpclient.GetStream();
            networkstream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkstream);
            string response = sr.ReadLine();

            return response;

        }
```

Comment: *Could my code be proofed to take this into account?* Yes.

Comment: Anything sent via TCP is guaranteed to arrive unless the connection is completely severed. Perhaps you're thinking of UDP? Alternatively, perhaps you're remembering that TCP is a stream so one "receive" might include a single "message", the tail end of one "message" and the start of another, several "messages", or just the start or end of a "message".

Comment: Your client actually can handle fragmented response from server, because it reads until "new line" character(s) appear on socket. Your server however does not do this (and client does not append newline at the end). Main thing is you should never expect the way you read data on your server to always return complete data sent by another side. You need to read specific number of bytes depending on "protocol" defined by yourself. In this case such protocol can be "all messages end by newline and do not contain newline themselves".

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the information. I was indeed talking about messages getting severed or joined tail to head. Good to know everything comes through. So, if I understand correctly my client is robust enough. 
I have now replaced the server side receiving code by a StreamReader doing an ReadLineAsync, using Evk's suggestion to separate all messages by newlines. As far as I can test it that seems to work well, but if anyone has additional feedback it's appreciated.